# DC Motor - need to go to 200-10,000 RPM

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, mechanical, robotics

I'm currently working on a setup with Raspberry Pi, a 12 V DC motor and a L298N driver. I need the motor to go from 12000 RPM to 200 RPM, or at least in that range - the only problem is that the L298N driver stalls under 10% Duty Cycle, and therefore can only reach 1200 RPM (I think that is how that works lol). I tried using the sleep() function in Python to emulate 1/10 of a 10% duty cycle to reach 120 RPM, but that doesn't work for reasons beyond my understanding. I have a device to check RPM. Any recommendations? I am willing to buy new parts or build stuff to make this work - let me know if I need to provide specifics for any of the parts.

As for what I've found - I need to understand how all of this works first off: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oai8qMH2yTU&ab_channel=engineer2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oai8qMH2yTU) something like this is what I saw, but it uses an Arduino not an RPi. I could possibly connect the two, buttttt I want to see if it is possible to do it using a RPi, and why it is happening.

Comment: Clear diagram of setup?

Comment: @SolarMike didnt make one. ill try to whip one up if i get time.

Comment: Code.  How does a driver stall?  As in motor it is driving stalls?  Does it work with no-load?